# div height fill rest of the white space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my orange div to get all of the white space in height. Im using 1920x1080 monitor. When i open bottom code in my page i have white space under red, blue and green div's. I wanna orange div to move my red, blue, green div's down and fill that white space under them.

The idea is site automatically to fill browser window without scrollbars.

I try to write 100% instead of 700px, but when my attribute is 100%, orange div disappear.

Can someone tell me why that is happening, where is my mistake, how can i prevent it.

Also is it there another way to give equal space to my red, blue and green div's? I calculate that 100% of page divided by 3 is 33.3333 in period. That's why i set my width to be 33.33% but it didn't fill page completely.

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
.pink{
   background-color: pink;
   height: 100px; width: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
.orange{
   background-color: orange;
   height: 700px; width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}


.red{
   background-color: red;
   height: 300px; width: 33.33%;
   position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.blue{
   background-color: blue;
   height: 300px; width: 33.33%;
   position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.green{
   background-color: green;
   height: 300px; width: 33.33%;
   position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pink"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="red"></div><div class="blue"></div><div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the white space in the background?

Comment: jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sgymotns/

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: you can equalise the width of red,blue and green by using flexbox.

Comment: @dreamhunter what info do you want to provide to make my question more clear?

Comment: @ZzozZ what you meant by **white space in height**?can you include an screen shot of the issue?

Comment: for percent height to work on an element, its parent must have a fixed height defined, only exception is the root element `html` i.e. root can have percentage height. So you can work backwards from there i.e. assign a percentage height to ur `wrapper` and then to `body` and then to `html`

Comment: Have you tried `margin:0` and `padding:0`? in `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

I've made use of

```
display: table
display: table-row
display: table-cell
```

The orange div will now fill the remaining height of the window.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgymotns/7/)

EDIT: I updated the fiddle. tidied the code a bit.

Comment: Yes that is what i wana to do. From where can i read more info how can i make this type of layouts ? Because for a first time i see " display: table-row/cell "

Comment: Honestly, I could not tell you its from just one place. I've just learnt over time and from experience.

Comment: Can you recommend me some nice written books and sites, blogs, podcasts?

Comment: I visit https://www.designernews.co/ from time to time. They showcase websites, I usually inspect them to see how they do effects I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

Give height:100% to parent div, body and html

```
body, html{
  height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
}
.orange{
   background-color: orange;
   height: 100%; width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Please check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muhsin84/bmgjdrxv/)**.

Comment: Orange div became too high and scrollbar appear. I wana to fill browser window without scroollbar.

Comment: is it fine to use jquery?

Comment: I think it will became too complex for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your `style`:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `orange` and `pink` inside a separate div from last three and use `display:flex;` on that div.

You can make three div eualwidth by using `display:flex` to the parent div and `flex:1` to the children divs. You don't necessarily have to use `width:33.33%;`

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  min-height:100vh;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.pink{
   background-color: pink;
   height: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.orange{
   background-color: orange;
   height:100%;
  width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-grow:1;
}
.wrapper2{
  position: relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  flex-shrink:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.red{
   background-color: red;
   height:100%;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   flex: 1;
}
.blue{
   background-color: blue;
   height:100%;
flex: 1;   position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.green{
   background-color: green;
   height:100%;
flex: 1;   position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pink"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @ZzozZ    I think this is what you meant to do with the orange one but I am still not sure about the last three ones (red,green,blue). if you could explain a little more about what those should be like.

Comment: it make's scrollbar for up and down. I wana divs to fill browser window without scroolbars.

Comment: okay. try now. `wrapper` has three vertical sections: `pink`, `orange` and `wrapper2`. And the `wrapper2` has three horizontal partitions `red`, `blue` and `green`.

Comment: now `wrapper2` and `pink` has fix height but, what ever screen size `orange` will fill rest of the screen without any scollbar appearing. except when there is too much content to fit in the screen.